# Is $f'$ continuous on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $f$ is continuous on a compact interval $[a,b]$ and has a continuous derivative  does it mean that $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ or $(a,b)$?

Comment: It should mean that $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. But some authors use weird terminology.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. I got confused a bit when I saw a proof in Rudin's book page 137. Thanks again! :)

Comment: It should mean that $f'$ is continuous on $[a,\,b]$ which essentially means that $f'$ is continuous on $(a,\,b)$, right continuous on $a$ and left continuous on $b$.

Comment: Can you provide the statement of the theorem you are considering?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on definitions of derivatives. Some authors do not introduce one-sided definitions of derivatives. But it should mean that $f'$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ and one-sided continuous at the two endpoints.